# Canvas, реализовать движение квадрата

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно реализовать движение квадрата. Если делать с помощью потока, то все работает, а если без, то показывается лишь начальное положение квадрата и через некоторое время конечное. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Первый код с потоком, второй без.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import _thread


def funkcia(event):
    _thread.start_new_thread(func, ())



def func():
    y = 0
    while y != 895:
        c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0)
        time.sleep(0.005)
        y += 1
    _thread.exit()


c = Canvas(width=1000, height=500, bg='grey80')
c.pack()
kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="red")

c.tag_bind(kvadrat, '<Button-1>', funkcia)

mainloop()
```

2

```
from tkinter import *
import time

c = Canvas(width=1000, height=500, bg='grey80')
c.pack()

kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="red")


def funkcia(event):
    y = 0
    while y != 895:
        c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0)
        time.sleep(0.005)
        y += 1


c.tag_bind(kvadrat, '<Button-1>', funkcia)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Бесконечный цикл блокирует обновление графического интерфейса (если он выполняется не в отдельном потоке). Вместо него лучше использовать метод `after`:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(width=1000, height=500, bg='grey80')
c.pack()

kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="red")


def funkcia(y):
    if y >= 895:
        return

    c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0)
    y += 1

    root.after(5, funkcia, y)


c.tag_bind(kvadrat, '<Button-1>', lambda event: funkcia(0))
root.mainloop()
```

Другой вариант - в цикле явно вызывать `root.update()` для обновления интерфейса:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(width=1000, height=500, bg='grey80')
c.pack()

kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="red")


def funkcia(event):
    y = 0
    while y != 895:
        c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0)
        time.sleep(0.005)
        root.update()
        y += 1


c.tag_bind(kvadrat, '<Button-1>', funkcia)
root.mainloop()
```