# К какой версии Python в tkinter добавили tag_bind()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

На RUso встретился вопрос, разбирая который столкнулся с неправильным применением tag_bind() из tkinter'а. В большинстве мануалов сети описан только bind().
Не удалось найти информацию с какой именно версии tag_bind() начал использоваться.

Пример неправомерного использования в задаче движения прямоугольника:
[здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914401/canvas-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)

Правильное решение задачи - не использовать привязку к событиям с помощью tag_bind().
Например, такое:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg="grey80")
c.pack()

kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="red")

def funkcia():
    c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0)
    if c.coords(kvadrat)[2] < 995:
        root.after(10, funkcia)

funkcia()

root.mainloop()
```

Однако, для полного и всестороннего обоснования не хватило именно дополнительной информации по данному методу.  Описание его нашел,  а дату внедрения -  увы и ах((  Нетути...  Печалька.

Comment: Собственно достаточно в репозитории питона открыть git blame, пролистать на несколько коммитов назад и увидеть 20 июня 1994 года https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1846882254324ac5eb0a96df493c7ab1eabd866e/Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py

Comment: А если интересует конкретно класс Canvas, то 8 августа 1994 года, и то это просто переименование метода bind https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ef8f88101a800e4e044e4ee602821a42f64f3dea

Comment: Спасибо, про дату на ГитХабе как-то и не подумал))
P.S. bind() для двух параметров, tag_bind() для трех.

Comment: @Assur, bind предназначен для виджетов, а [`tag_bind`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_bind-method) для объектов на `Canvas`. Если нужно добавить реакцию, например, на клик по прямоугольнику на `Canvas`, то нужно использовать `tag_bind`, а не `bind`. Не знаю, с чего вы решили, что это "неправомерно".

Comment: Я добавил ответ к тому вопросу. Вы можете убедиться, что этот метод вполне "правомерный".

Comment: Ясно одно - мне рано отвечать на подобные вопросы)) Спасибо, что уделили время. Python не первый мой язык,  но на стадии погружения хотелось закопаться поглубже в задачи и лучше чем RUso мне ничего не посоветовали для углубления в Python. Пока активно режут "репу", если где-то пытаюсь строить из себя гуру))

Comment: @Assur репа - дело наживное. Когда переходил на python, мне очень помог checkio.org, как раз позволяет ознакомиться с основными средствами языка (мне помог переучиться с предыдущего языка по сути).